# Date - Month in bash without leading 0 or space?

Tags: bash, date

Anyone know how to display the date like this?

```
7-1-2019
```

I currently have this which adds leading 0 to the month

```
$(LC_ALL=nn_NO.UTF-8 date +'%-d-%m-%Y')
```

like this

```
7-01-2019
```

I use these in lynx dump commands

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You have already removed the padding for the day, why not do the same for the month?

```
$ date +'%-d-%-m-%Y'
7-1-2019
```

Here's a list of all padding modifiers from `man date`:

> By default, date pads numeric fields with zeroes.  The following
>   optional flags may follow '%':
>
> `-`      (hyphen) do not pad the field
>
> `_`      (underscore) pad with spaces
>
> `0`      (zero) pad with zeros
>
> `^`      use upper case if possible
>
> `#`      use opposite case if possible
>
> After any flags comes an optional field width, as a decimal number;
>   then an optional modifier, which is either E to use the locale's
>   alternate representations if available, or O to use the locale's
>   alternate numeric symbols if available.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt actually know I was doing that.