# Month Format in Unix

Tags: shell, date, unix, unix-timestamp, yearmonth

I am trying to create a shell script for auditing purpose. In my source data the value of month contains like yyyym(20217) format. I need to extract the records based on this month type.

is there any dateformat to print like this in Unix?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean and that format looks very dangerous: imagine that you also add the day number, does "2021121" stand for the first of December 2021 or the 21 of January? (Normal formatting is "yyyymmdd")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066437/date-month-in-bash-without-leading-0-or-space